# Terraform tomap({k = v}) == { k = v } field false, why?

Tags: terraform

```sh
terraform version

Terraform v1.0.1
on linux_amd64
```

[tomap function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/tomap.html) states

> Since Terraform's concept of a map requires all of the elements to be of the same type, mixed-typed elements will be converted to the most general type

In the example below, there is a single item in the map. Should `tomap()` do nothing? (ie return the same value). It looks like `tomap()` had changed the original single-item map.

```
> {mykey = 12} == tomap({mykey = 12})
false
```

Inspecting the details, `tomap()` seems to return a kind of `tomap` type. How does the type conversion work exactly?

```
> tomap({mykey = 12})
tomap({
  "mykey" = 12
})

> {mykey = 12}
{
  "mykey" = 12
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax `{mykey = 12}` creates an `object`, and `tomap({mykey = 12})` turns this object into a `map`. So you are comparing and `object` with a `map` which are different.  This is explained in the [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/map.html):

> The { ... } braces **construct an object value**, and then the tomap function then converts it to a map.

If you want to create `{mykey = 12}` as map variable, you can do:

```
variable "a" {
  type=map(number)
  default = {
    "mykey" = 12
  }
}
```

Without `type`, you are again getting an `object`.